# Check for a number to be a ** b

Tags: c, algorithm, math

My question is write an efficient algorithm to check whether a given number *n* is of the form *a<sup>b</sup>* where *a, b* are integers >= 2. I have tried the following but it is not time efficient.

```
int cnt = 0;
long long i, sq = sqrt(n);
for (i = 2; i <= sq; i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
        cnt++;
        n = n / i;
        while (n % i == 0) {
            n /= i;
            cnt++;

        }
        if (n == 1) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (cnt >= 2) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: Check out http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-perfect-power-in-polynomial-time.

Comment: Well, XOR is an invertible operation, so this should be really easy...

Comment: @biziclop Question is marked as C/C++ and the `^` would be an XOR in those languages

Comment: Also your implementation seems to be wrong, it gives me `true` for `n=12`.

Comment: Yes, the implementation is not only slow but wrong.  In fact, once you find *any* divisor, you never should return to the divisor hunt loop (why?)

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you meant `pow(a, b)` not `a^b`, since `^` in C/C++ is the [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operator.

Your problem is known as **detecting [perfect powers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_power)** and there is a lot of literature you can find in the internet.

For example: [*Detecting perfect powers in linear time*](http://cr.yp.to/papers/powers-ams.pdf) by Daniel Bernstein.

Answer (score 2):

You can both fix your code and speed it up considerably by replacing:

```
if (n == 1) break;
```

with

```
return (n == 1);
```

Then since you went to the trouble of computing `sqrt(n)`, might as well have an early exit for perfect squares:

```
if (n == sq * sq) return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Idea:

```
if n = 3^5 then:
     ln(n) / ln(3)   = 5
exp( ln(n) /    5  ) = 3
```

Sample JavaScript code, open inspector/console for results (easily convertible to C):

http://jsfiddle.net/8wuUK/

```
function powerSplit( n ){
  console.log('n =', n);
  var log = Math.log, exp = Math.exp, abs = Math.abs,
      floor = Math.floor, round = Math.round;
  var epsilon = 0.001;
  var logn = log( n );
  var pow = floor( log(n) / log(2) ) + 1;
  do{
    pow --;
    var base = exp( logn / pow );
    var intbase = round( base );
    if( abs( base - intbase ) > epsilon ) continue;
    //console.log( base, intbase, pow, isExactPower( n, intbase ) );
    if( isExactPower( n, intbase ))  return 'n = ' + intbase +' ^ ' + pow;
  }while( pow >= 1 );
  return 'n is not a power';
}

function isExactPower( n, base ){
  while( n > 1 ){
    if( n % base ) return false;
    n /= base;
  };
  return true;
};
```